# What does the "Lia" variable stand for in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, nomenclature

For example, we see in the documentation for `ismember`:

```
[Lia,Locb] = ismember(A,B)
```

The `Locb` seems to stand for "location in B". What is the meaning of `Lia`? Could it be something like "line in A"?

Answer (score 7):

Logical index to A.

From [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html#outputarg_Lia):

> Lia — Logical index to A
>
> vector | matrix | N-D array
>
> Logical index to
>   A, returned as a vector, matrix or N-D array containing 1 (true)
>   wherever the values (or rows) in A are members of B. Elsewhere, it
>   returns 0 (false).
>
> Lia is an array of the same size as A, unless you specify the 'rows'
>   flag.
>
> If the 'rows' flag is specified or if A is a table, Lia is a column
>   vector with the same number of rows as A.

Edit: See also: [Logical Indexing in MATLAB](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/)

Comment: doh! should have scrolled to the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: @Alex it happens to the best of us ;)